# Auto center the marker on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, zooming, google-maps-markers

I have a marker on google maps on my website. I want the marker to be always at the center of the map whether we zoom in or zoom out.

In the sense, lets say the marker is at boston and the zoom level of map is in such way that we can see the whole Massachusetts state, no matter at which part of the state we zoom into, Boston should be at the center of the map with a newer zoomed level, same thing should happen even when we zoom out.

Comment: It's customary to post questions about specific code to get help resolving a problem. Questions of the sort, "is it possible" aren't generally received very well. And I'm sure it's unintentional, but "please give me a code sample" comes across as overly demanding. Just a gentle suggestion: try checking the [Map section of the API-Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map), check out the `zoom_changed` event and `Map.setCenter()`. If you are having trouble after that, update your question with more detail and you will find many willing to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the google docs

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
// 3 seconds after the center of the map has changed, pan back to the
// marker.
window.setTimeout(function() {
  map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
}, 3000);
```

});

You can also use something like this to center the map on an event `map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());`

Comment: A small correction to the code, I wanted the marker to be as the center only when the zoom levels are changed. Hence I replaced `center_changed` to `zoom_changed`. Also the 3000 is the milliseconds which can changed to a smaller value if you want quicker updates to the maps